# How to show the current day of the week in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheets that works as my To-Do list, and I want to make a cell that displays the current day of the week in text and updates itself every day. For example, Monday or Friday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a build-in function for that in Google Sheets.

```
=today()
```

Just write that in a cell of your choice. You only then need to format the cell and display the date as you like by going to `Menu`--> `Format` --> `Number` --> `More Formats` --> `More date and time formats`.

[image: date-01]

**You can choose and also create your own variations.**

[image]

Comment: What I meant is that it would show the name of the day of the week, for example, Monday or Friday. My bad for not elaborating.

Comment: Welcome. Please have a look at the images.

Comment: It's great how much you can customize within that sub-menu "format: ... "more date and time formats" " !  Saved me a lot of time and headache

Comment: @Nathan One the hidden little gems in Google Sheets. :)

Answer (score 12):

solution without formatting:

```
=Text(TODAY(),"dddd")
```

[image]

see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139

Comment: That's smart; a lot simpler than trying to use WEEKDAY.